# How do you implement an async action delegate method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await, c#-5.0

## A little background information.

I am learning the Web API stack and I am trying to encapsulate all data in the form of a "`Result`" object with parameters such as `Success` and `ErrorCodes`.

Different methods however, would produce different results and error codes but the result object would generally be instantiated the same way.

To save some time and also to learn more about `async`/`await` capabilities in C#, I am trying to wrap all the method bodies of my web API actions in an asynchronous action delegate but got caught in a bit of a snag...

### **Given the following classes:**

```
public class Result
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public List<int> ErrorCodes{ get; set; }
}

public async Task<Result> GetResultAsync()
{
    return await DoSomethingAsync<Result>(result =>
    {
        // Do something here
        result.Success = true;
        
        if (SomethingIsTrue)
        {
            result.ErrorCodes.Add(404);
            result.Success = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to write a method that performs an action on a `Result` object and return it. Normally through synchronous methods it would be

```
public T DoSomethingAsync<T>(Action<T> resultBody) where T : Result, new()
{
    T result = new T();
    resultBody(result);
    return result;
}
```

But how do I transform this method into an asynchronous method using `async`/`await`?

This is what I have tried:

```
public async Task<T> DoSomethingAsync<T>(Action<T, Task> resultBody) 
    where T: Result, new()
{
    // But I don't know what do do from here.
    // What do I await?
}
```

Comment: If you're `new`-ing up the `T`, why does your method need to be asynchronous? AFAIK in code *using* asynchronous APIs, you only need to propagate the `async`ness from other methods you use.

Comment: Sorry I'm fairly new to this still, what do you mean when you say you only need to propagate, and what does new-ing the T have to do with it?

Comment: Why are you even trying to do this async? More often in not in webserver situations doing fake async by wrapping synchronous code in tasks (like you are trying to do) is ***slower*** than just doing it synchronously.

Comment: @AlbinAnke By "propagate" I mean that **if** you're calling a .NET method like `Stream.ReadAsync()` in a method, that method should itself be asynchronous, and return a `Task<T>` where `T` is what you'd have returned were the method synchronous. The idea is that this way, every caller of your method can then "asynchronously wait" (I don't know what a good term for this is) for the underlying `Stream.ReadAsync()` to complete. A metaphor for this you can use is that async is "infectious", and spreads from low-level built-in I/O into other code whose results depend on those of said I/O.

Answer (score 418, accepted):

The `async` equivalent of `Action<T>` is `Func<T, Task>`, so I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
public async Task<T> DoSomethingAsync<T>(Func<T, Task> resultBody)
    where T : Result, new()
{
  T result = new T();
  await resultBody(result);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: @Stephen Clearly I'm Trying to implement some similar into a MVVM ligth Messenger, Can I implement the same way ?

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez: I'm not familiar with their kind of messaging, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Func is not the async equivalent of Action. Func is a function delegate which expects a return value whereas action doesn't require to have a return value.

Comment: @DFSFOT: The async equivalent of a `void` method is a `Task`-returning method; thus, the async equivalent of `Action` is `Func<Task>`, and the async equivalent of `Action<T>` is `Func<T, Task>`. More info [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/02/synchronous-and-asynchronous-delegate.html).

Comment: @StephenCleary You're right, my bad. What do you do when you have an async call in your action that isn't supposed to return anything tho?

Comment: @DFSFOT: An async method should return `Task` when it doesn't have a return value. If it uses the `async` keyword, then the actual `Task` instance will be created by a state machine, not the function directly.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I am looking for, you are awesome. Is there a way to do this without initializing the generic parameter? What if the generic parameter is a class with a non-default constructor? Is there a way to make that work as well?

Comment: @EgeAydın: You'll need to get a `T` instance from somewhere. You can pass `default`, which will be `null` for reference types. For anything more complex than `default` or `new T()` you'll need to either use an existing `T` or use a factory.

Comment: Shouldn't the method signature be as follows? `async Task<T> DoSomethingAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> resultBody)`

Comment: @JohnB: No; `Func<T, Task>` is an asynchronous method that takes a parameter of type `T` and has no return value. `Func<Task<T>>` is an asynchronous method that takes no parameters and returns a value of type `T`.

Comment: 10 years ago, you are still smarter than I am today.

Comment: No. Just more experience in a technology that suddenly became popular.

Answer (score -15):

*So I believe the way to implement this is:*

```
public Task<T> DoSomethingAsync<T>(Action<T> resultBody) where T : Result, new()
{
    return Task<T>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        T result = new T();
        resultBody(result);
        return result;
    });
}
```

Comment: You should avoid `Task.Run` (and even more so `StartNew`) on ASP.NET.

Comment: What is a better way to do this?

Comment: I posted an answer, and upvoted @svick's answer too. They're both good answers.