# wpf dispatcher.invokeasync Func<T,T,TResult>

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

Similar but different to this question [How do you implement an async action delegate method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20624667/how-do-you-implement-an-async-action-delegate-method)

Hi,
I have a method that takes two arguments and returns a result,
In calculating the result it calls an awaitable function
The arguments to the method are only accessible on another thread, so I'm using dispatcher.CheckAccess, dispatcher.Invoke or dispatcher.InvokeAsync.
The best result I got so far is something that builds and runs, but the function never got hit even though dispatcher invoke was called.

I found the example in the referenced thread confusing due to the naming T result, whereas I thought T was an in parameter.

my function looks like this:

```
private async Task<TResult>> fn(object arg1, object arg2){return await x(arg1,arg2);}
```

dispatcher code looks something like this:

```
if (dispatcher.CheckAccess())
result=    await fn(a,b);
else
result=dispatcher.InvokeAsync<TResult>(fn(a,b)); // this is incorrect syntax
```

Hopefully Stephen Cleary can rescue me :-) I couldn't find an example like this in Concurrency in C# Cookbook. Probably I'm looking at this wrong way?

Thanks
Martin

Comment: If you know that your call of `InvokeAsync` is incorrect why not to go to MSDN and know proper syntax? 1) I see no overload of `InvokeAsync` that takes `Func<..., ...>` as an argument; 2) In C# you can't pass method call as an argument. Probably you want to use `InvokeAsync(() => fn(a,b))`

Comment: While [mm8's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44631088/263693) will get your code to compile, I generally recommend architecting the code so that background operations do not require the presence of a UI layer. E.g., getting the `TResult` first and *then* starting the background operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looking at this with a fresh mind this morning. I went back to the code that ran, but didn't produce results. Turns out the thread associated with the dispatcher was a background thread in state waitsleepjoin. The object I needed was an image. By freezing the image, I found I didn't need to worry about threading issues at all - there was no dispatcher available.
Hope this helps someone else.
Martin

Answer (score 1):

The `InvokeAsync` method accepts an `Action` or a `Func<T>` that you may await:

```
await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(async () => await fn(a, b));
```